# nodejs - change https server certificate

Tags: node.js, https, proxy

I am working on a https proxy and I need to change the https certificate on the fly. For example:

1. a client request www.google.com
2. the https server(proxy) must create a certificate with CommonName = www.google.com
3. the https server must send this certificate to client

The https server takes as parameters the key and certificate, but I don't need a static certificate, I need to change the certificate on every different request.

Any ideas?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165570/https-proxy-server-in-node-js ?

Comment: No. I catch the HTTPS requests already, and forward the request, but the SSL certificate is invalid.