# Node.js proxy server with https support

Tags: windows, node.js, https, proxy

I'm trying to write proxy server that will proxy (almost) all http/s requests. Almost all because I need catch requests for some specific https url's and as response send the file from hdd instead of real response from the web.

Whole solution should works as proxy in the browser and have to work on windows 7. I started with my own proxy based on express.js. It works great ... but unfortunately not via https. Then I was trying to use several existing node.js proxy servers from github (https://github.com/horaci/node-mitm-proxy, https://github.com/Hypermediaisobar/hyperProxy and few other) but any of them worked in windows environment on https (or I don't know how to congiure them).

Finally I found somewhere in internet code (don't have the link to source) which works via https (see code below). The problems with this code is, that I can't find right way to check the incoming request url and depending on the request url handle them in different ways.
 I will be grateful if someone could help me with that.

```
var http = require('http');
var net = require('net');

var debugging = 0;

var regex_hostport = /^([^:]+)(:([0-9]+))?$/;

function getHostPortFromString(hostString, defaultPort) {
  var host = hostString;
  var port = defaultPort;

  var result = regex_hostport.exec(hostString);
  if (result != null) {
    host = result[1];
    if (result[2] != null) {
      port = result[3];
    }
  }

  return( [ host, port ] );
}

// handle a HTTP proxy request
function httpUserRequest(userRequest, userResponse) {
  var httpVersion = userRequest['httpVersion'];
  var hostport = getHostPortFromString(userRequest.headers['host'], 80);

  // have to extract the path from the requested URL
  var path = userRequest.url;
  result = /^[a-zA-Z]+:\/\/[^\/]+(\/.*)?$/.exec(userRequest.url);
  if (result) {
    if (result[1].length > 0) {
      path = result[1];
    } else {
      path = "/";
    }
  }

  var options = {
    'host': hostport[0],
    'port': hostport[1],
    'method': userRequest.method,
    'path': path,
    'agent': userRequest.agent,
    'auth': userRequest.auth,
    'headers': userRequest.headers
  };

  var proxyRequest = http.request(
    options,
    function (proxyResponse) {
      userResponse.writeHead(proxyResponse.statusCode, proxyResponse.headers);

      proxyResponse.on('data', function (chunk) {
          userResponse.write(chunk);
        }
      );

      proxyResponse.on('end',
        function () {
          userResponse.end();
        }
      );
    }
  );

  proxyRequest.on('error', function (error) {
      userResponse.writeHead(500);
      userResponse.write(
        "<h1>500 Error</h1>\r\n<p>Error was <pre>" + error + "</pre></p>\r\n</body></html>\r\n";
      );
      userResponse.end();
    }
  );

  userRequest.addListener('data', function (chunk) {
      proxyRequest.write(chunk);
    }
  );

  userRequest.addListener('end', function () {
      proxyRequest.end();
    }
  );
}

    function main() {
      var port = 5555; // default port if none on command line

      // check for any command line arguments
      for (var argn = 2; argn < process.argv.length; argn++) {
        if (process.argv[argn] === '-p') {
          port = parseInt(process.argv[argn + 1]);
          argn++;
          continue;
        }

        if (process.argv[argn] === '-d') {
          debugging = 1;
          continue;
        }
      }

      if (debugging) {
        console.log('server listening on port ' + port);
      }

      // start HTTP server with custom request handler callback function
      var server = http.createServer(httpUserRequest).listen(port);

      server.addListener('checkContinue', function (request, response){
        console.log(request);
        response.writeContinue();
      });
      // add handler for HTTPS (which issues a CONNECT to the proxy)
      server.addListener(
        'connect',
        function (request, socketRequest, bodyhead) {
          var url = request['url'];
          var httpVersion = request['httpVersion'];
          var hostport = getHostPortFromString(url, 443);

          // set up TCP connection
          var proxySocket = new net.Socket();

          proxySocket.connect(
            parseInt(hostport[1]), hostport[0],
            function () {

                  console.log("ProxySocket: " + hostport[1] + " | " + hostport[0]);
                  proxySocket.write(bodyhead);

              // tell the caller the connection was successfully established
              socketRequest.write("HTTP/" + httpVersion + " 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n");
            }
          );

          proxySocket.on('data', function (chunk) {
              socketRequest.write(chunk);
            }
          );

          proxySocket.on('end', function () {
              socketRequest.end();
            }
          );

          socketRequest.on('data', function (chunk) {
              proxySocket.write(chunk);
            }
          );

          socketRequest.on('end', function () {
              proxySocket.end();
            }
          );

          proxySocket.on('error', function (err) {
              socketRequest.write("HTTP/" + httpVersion + " 500 Connection error\r\n\r\n");
              socketRequest.end();
            }
          );

          socketRequest.on('error', function (err) {
              proxySocket.end();
        }
          );
        }
      ); // HTTPS connect listener
    }

    main();
```

Comment: Related, and solution provided at http://stackoverflow.com/a/32104777/786389

Answer (score 0):

are you asking for

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.secure
req.secure -> https

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.protocol
req.protocol -> http

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.host
req.host

req.url

this should all be on your userRequest

I probably did not understand your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line:
  var https = require('https');
And when you are making regular http requests, use http.request, and for the ssl requests, https.request.