# How to get the complete url from a https request when the "connect" event is emitted?

Tags: node.js, https, proxy, forward-proxy

The following code is a simplified part of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32104777/9715117) answer about a proxy, just in case:

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {}).listen(8080);
server.addListener('connect', function (req, socket, bodyhead) {});
```

The listener inside `createServer` get executed when the request is `http` and the listener of the `connect` event get executed when the request is `https`.
The thing is I cannot get the complete url from `req` in `function (req, socket, bodyhead) {}`, `req.url` only shows the domain and the port number e.g  `www.google-analytics.com:443`  I'd like it to be something like `https://www.google-analytics.com/a/b?f=...`

EDIT: I tried with `` new URL(req.url, `http://${req.url}`) `` with no avail, for a request like `https://www.example.com/favicon.ico` this returns an object:

```
Symbol(context): URLContext {flags: 258, scheme: 'www.wordreference.com:', username: '', password: '', host: null, …}
Symbol(query): URLSearchParams {Symbol(query): Array(0), Symbol(context): URL}
hash: ""
host: ""
hostname: ""
href: "www.example.com:443"
origin: "null"
password: ""
pathname: "443"
port: ""
protocol: "www.example.com:"
search: ""
searchParams: URLSearchParams
username: ""
Symbol(cannot-be-base): (...)
Symbol(cannot-have-username-password-port): (...)
Symbol(special): (...)
```

Only shows the domain and the port.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not possible for a proxy get the *url*, only the domain part, since the request being of https type is encrypted and the proxy cannot see not even the url, here is the [link](https://unit42.paloaltonetworks.com/wireshark-tutorial-decrypting-https-traffic/).

> HTTPS traffic often reveals a domain name. For example, when viewing
> https://www.wireshark.org in a web browser, a pcap would show
> [www.wireshark.org](http://www.wireshark.org) as the server name for this traffic when viewed in a
> customized Wireshark column display. Unfortunately, we don’t know
> other details like the actual URL or data returned from the server.